# How to prevent a TextBox from growing vertically when I enter text?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `TextBox` that grows in size vertically when I enter text. This is how it appears:

*(normal size on the left, increased size with text on the right)*
[image]

This is a problem because it pushes everything else on the screen down as soon as I enter text.

This is how I create the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" FontSize="30" 
    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Red"
    TextAlignment="Center" InputScope="Number" />
```

I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary in terms of how the `TextBox` is created.

What can I do to either prevent the `TextBox` from growing, or to prevent everything on the screen getting pushed down when it grows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the "Height" attribute. That should prevent the box from growing.

Comment: Depending on the situation, MaxHeight may also be useful.